# I`ve got error A2004:symbol type conflict when tried to import C function in assembler

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++, x86, masm

I've got error `A2004:symbol` type conflict when tried to import C function in assembler but I tried to make it in different ways but every time I'm getting same error.

**C code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int __stdcall funcName1(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int answer = a*b-c;
    return answer;
}
```

**Assembler code**

```
.586
.model  flat, C
.stack
.data
    num1 dd 2h
    num2 dd 2h
    num3 dd 1h
extern funcName1:far
.CODE
FuncName PROC
    mov eax, offset num3
    push eax
    mov eax, offset num2
    push eax
    mov eax, offset num1
    push eax
    call funcName1
    pop  ebx
    pop  ebx
    pop  ebx
    ret
FuncName ENDP
END FuncName
```

I don't know what to improve it. It's my first time with assembly. I'm trying to find an information but I cant.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. Then come back and provide a [mre] by [edit]ing your question, and add needed information. -- Which line is mentioned for the error? -- What compiler and assembler are you using? With what command lines?

Comment: I don't know of any C compiler that will make `far` calls in 32-bit mode.  A flat memory model is standard, with segment base = 0 for CS/DS/ES/SS, and near call/return.  Notice that you're only passing the `offset` part of the ds:num3 locial address, because that's the normal thing for a flat memory model; the offset *is* the 32-bit address.  So do the same with function calls and don't make them `far`.

Comment: As Peter poijted out `far` doesn't apply to 32-bit flat model and you are confusing MASM by saying that `funcName1` is `FAR`. You might have meant `funcName1:proc`. Even then since you are making your C function STDCALL you have to deal with name mangling. Rather than `extern funcName1:far` use something like `funcName1 PROTO STDCALL, arga:DWORD, argb:DWORD, argc:DWORD`  . Specifying STDCALL will do name mangling for you when you do `call funcName1`. You will also need to remove the C++ name mangling by using `extern "C"` like `extern "C" int __stdcall funcName1(int a, int b, int c)`

Comment: Also note since `funcName1` is STDCALL the function will clean the stack so you need to remove all the `pop` instructions after the stdcall function call as the parameters have already been removed for you. If you were to use CDECL instead of STDCALL then you would have to clean up the parameters. I'm not sure if you are required to use STDCALL, but CDECL would have worked more the way you seemed to expect it.

Comment: As well you use `OFFSET` to move the address of `num`, `num2`, and `num3` into the registers and push pointers on the stack. Your function requires just the values. You need to remove `offset` from each of the `mov` instructions to move the value from that label into the registers, and not the addresses.

Comment: Lastly if you use the `PROTO` line I gave you above you can avoid all the manual pushes by instead invoking the function with parameters like this `invoke funcName1, num1, num2, num3`. MASM will handle the calling convention by pushing the parameters in the right order and dealing with the stack as needed. the `invoke` directive in MASM understand the STDCALL and CDECL calling conventions. and will generate the underlying instructions necessary to carry out the call.